# C++ template interface auto-resolve assigned type

Tags: c++, templates, interface, copy

In Java, you can do the following

```
List<int> myList = new ArrayList<int>();
Iterator iter = myList.Iterator();
```

Even though Iterator is a generic/template interface, it doesn't have to explicitly be given its template type when getting assigned from another generic. 
It's able to use the type that's already present in myList<.int>

I'm trying to set up a similar framework in C++ that wraps the STL libraries. I have the following working.

```
List<int>* myList = new ArrayList<int>();
Iterator<int>* iter = myList->GetIterator();
```

Is there any way to get rid of the `<int>` when I declare the Iterator pointer? It works fine the way it is, it would just be a lot more convenient if I didn't have to grab the type every time I want to iterate.

I want it to look like this.

```
List<int>* myList = new ArrayList<int>();
Iterator* iter = myList->GetIterator();
```

My Iterator class looks like this

```
template <class T>
class Iterator
{
public:
    virtual boolean HasNext() = 0;
    virtual T Next() = 0;
    virtual void Remove() = 0;
};
```

Cheers.

Comment: Well if you are using C++11 you have `auto`

Comment: I'm tempted to say save your Java-like code for Java. C++ is not Java, and trying to force it to be with ArrayList and pointers and everything will only really make sense to you, not to mention the problems you'll undoubtedly run into and have to work around.

Comment: Why use a pointer for `myList`? Remember that C++ is not garbage-collected, so if you forget to `delete` `myList` you have a memory leak. And finally, if you want to program in Java then program in Java, and stop making C++ behave like something it's not. It's a lot more work than it's worth, and few (if any) besides you would want to use it.

Comment: Stop trying so hard to make C++ another language. It's great the way it is.

Comment: wow, why all the hate? We're on an embedded system so we're stuck using C++. The STL library has confusing and unfamiliar syntax so we're extending it to be a lot easier to use. The developers we have on this project will find this syntax much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shafik said, you can use `auto`, which is probably the easiest way.  The other way is called type erasure. It boils down to having iterator be a non-templated class that has a templated constructor and a member variable that is a pointer to an inherited class. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/oz18T05o/) for a full explanation.

To get you started:

```
class IteratorBase
{

}

template <typename T>
class IteratorDerived : IteratorBase
{
...
}


class Iterator
{
    template <typename T> Iterator(const T & _itr) : mIterator(new IteratorDerived<T>(_itr)){}

    shared_ptr<IteratorBase> mIterator;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look more into this.